# Matching package version string in /bin/sh

Tags: regex, shell

I'm trying to match given string and match it to a package version in a /bin/sh script:

```
if test "x$version" = "x"; then
  version="latest";
  info "Version parameter not defined, assuming latest";
else
  info "Version parameter defined: $version";
  info "Matching version to package version"
  case "$version" in
    [^4.0.]*)
      $package_version='1.0.1'
      ;;
    [^4.1.]*)
      $package_version='1.1.1'
      ;;
    [^4.2.]*)
      $package_version='1.2.6'
      ;;
    *)
      critical "Unable to match requested version to package version"
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
fi
```

However, when I run it I get an error:

```
23:38:47 +0000 INFO: Version parameter defined: 4.0.0
23:38:47 +0000 INFO: Matching Puppet version to puppet-agent package version (See http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/about_agent.html for more details)
23:38:47 +0000 CRIT: Unable to match requested puppet version to puppet-agent version - Check http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/about_agent.html
23:38:47 +0000 CRIT: Please file a bug report at https://github.com/petems/puppet-install-shell/
23:38:47 +0000 CRIT:
23:38:47 +0000 CRIT: Version: 4.0.0
```

I'm using the same regex that worked for me in another part of the script:, and it seems to work there:

```
if test "$version" = 'latest'; then
        apt-get install -y puppet-common puppet
      else
        case "$version" in
          [^2.7.]*)
            info "2.7.* Puppet deb package tied to Facter < 2.0.0, specifying Facter 1.7.4"
            apt-get install -y puppet-common=$version-1puppetlabs1 puppet=$version-1puppetlabs1 facter=1.7.4-1puppetlabs1 --force-yes
            ;;
          *)
            apt-get install -y puppet-common=$version-1puppetlabs1 puppet=$version-1puppetlabs1 --force-yes
            ;;
        esac
      fi
```

What am I missing?

Full version of the script is here: https://github.com/petems/puppet-install-shell/blob/fix_puppet_agent_install/install_puppet_agent.sh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `case ... esac` in a POSIX shell script uses [(glob-style) *patterns*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html), not regular expressions (while the two are distantly related, there are fundamental differences).

  - To get true regex matching in a `sh` script, you'd have to use `expr` with `:`, though it's probably not needed here.
- To test for a *prefix* match, use `<prefix>*` in a `case` branch - case branches are always matched against the *entire* argument - no need for anchoring (which patterns don't support).

  - As an aside, what you're attempting would not even work for prefix matching as a *regex*. E.g., `[^4.0.]` is the same as `[^.04]` - i.e., a *negated* character *class*: it matches *one* character if it is neither `.` nor `0` nor `4`.
- When *assigning* to a variable in a POSIX shell script, do *not* use `$`.

To put it all together:

```
#/bin/sh

if [ "$version" = "" ]; then
  version="latest";
  info "Version parameter not defined, assuming latest"
else
  info "Version parameter defined: $version";
  info "Matching version to package version"
  case "$version" in
    4.0.*)
      package_version='1.0.1'
      ;;
    4.1.*)
      package_version='1.1.1'
      ;;
    4.2.*)
      package_version='1.2.6'
      ;;
    *)
      critical "Unable to match requested version to package version"
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
fi
```

Comment: Perfect thanks! I'm still curious why the old one worked ok earlier in the script? But either way I'll refactor both to use your example, as it does seem like a better approach :)

Comment: @PeterSouter: My pleasure; I have no explanation for why the older one worked, unless the `*` branch happened to work as well.